# Duplicate Entry Gradle Error Using Firebase UI Dependancy

Tags: android, gradle, firebase

I'm using Firebase UI in my app but having difficulty building the app after adding the Firebase UI dependency. It complains about 
'com/google/android/gms/auth/api/signin/internal/zzf.class' being duplicated, so I added an exclude statement for it but without success. Here is how my build.gradle look like:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion "24.0.0"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "appfactory.app.chatapp"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 24
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

        multiDexEnabled true
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE-FIREBASE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'com/google/android/gms/auth/api/signin/internal/zzf.class'
    } 
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'

    compile 'com.android.support:design:24.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.0'

    // Displaying images
    compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.6.1'

    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:10.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:10.0.0'
    // FirebaseUI Auth only
    compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:0.6.2'

}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

And here is the error I get

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'.
>   com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: com/google/android/gms/auth/api/signin/internal/zzf.class

Comment: Try 9.8.0 instead of 10 for firebase database and auth..

Comment: You are correct! Thank you, please make it an answer so I mark it.

Comment: Here you go ..Put as an answer .. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the readme file of [FirebaseUI for Android — UI Bindings for Firebase](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android)

> Each version of FirebaseUI has dependency on a fixed version of these
>   libraries, defined as the variable firebase_version in
>   common/constants.gradle

In your case you are using 0.6.2 and the corresponding `com.google.firebase:firebase` version is `9.8.0`

So changing

```
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:10.0.0'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:10.0.0'
```

to

```
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:9.8.0'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:9.8.0'
```

Should fix the problem.

Comment: Appreciate the help, although they said that firebase-ui-auth:1.0.0 will work with firebase-auth:9.8.0, but it didn't. Hope they fix that. Thanks